# VHDL Signal changes on the edge of two separate signals

Tags: signals, vhdl

I was looking at this post
[Flip-Flop triggered on the edge of two signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301673/flip-flop-triggered-on-the-edge-of-two-signals)

I have a similar problem, my circuit will have one signal act as a "Start" and another as "End" to control a transmitter. The logic is something like this:

```
if (start) then 
    running <= true 
else if (end) then 
    running <= false
```

The solution provided by "Marty" answers this problem. 
In one of his replies, "giroy" said: 
"I realize this is not the best way of doing it, but that is outside my control and i'm stuck working with it"

I am new to VHDL and wondering what is a better way of implementing the problem above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flip-Flop triggered on the edge of two signals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301673/flip-flop-triggered-on-the-edge-of-two-signals)

Comment: You may have to define 'better' and 'best' from your expectation. SO tends to discourage questions with those subjective-looking words.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need a (clocked) RS-FF:

- `set` = start
- `reset` = end

Example code for a SR-FF:

```
process(Clock)
begin
  if rising_edge(Clock) then
    if (set = '1') then
      reg <= '1';
    elsif (reset = '1') then
      reg <= '0';
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```